# optional hasOne in laravel 7 for relationship confusion not working

Tags: laravel

I have a one-to-one relationship I am trying to get to work in laravel.

I have two tables `users` and `others`

users table

- name
- email
- password

others tables

```
- user_id
- each_seminar_internal
- each_seminar_foreign
And ...
```

User.php

```
public function other()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Other::class);
}
```

blade.php

```
<ul>
   <li>{{ optional(auth()->user()->other)->each_seminar_foreign }}</li>
   <li>{{ optional(auth()->user()->other)->each_seminar_foreign}}</li>
</ul>
```

I see this error.

> Trying to get property 'each_seminar_internal' of non-object (View: C:\xampp3\htdocs\projects\tehran\moorabionline\resources\views\Home\steps\ten.blade.php)

Comment: in this first check Auth::check() and then this condition applied

Comment: I write `@dd(auth()->check())` I see `true`

Comment: Yes, what can I do to avoid error?

Comment: @DeveloperLaravel.can you full blade code

Comment: may be `@php isset((auth()->user()->other)->each_seminar_foreign) ? (auth()->user()->other)->each_seminar_foreign : null @endphp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing `optional(auth()->user())->other->each_seminar_foreign`. If that is also failing you will have to add a second optional `optional(optional(auth()->user())->other)->each_seminar_foreign`.